# CategoryAttribute and PropertyInfo

Tags: c#

I have a class that includes several hundred Properties. Each of the properties was declared with a [CategoryAttribute("My Category Name")] attribute clause so that it will display nicely in a PropertyGrid. I would like to make use of this same CategoryAttribute attribute to set the values of all the properties in the class that were labeled with specific categoryAttribute catagories. The code below compiles and runs but it doesn't accomplish the task because att_coll doesn't contain the CategoryAttribute attribute that I expected that it would. Does anyone know how to do this? Thanks so much.

```
    class my_class
    {
        [CategoryAttribute("Category One")]
        public int property_1
        {
             get { return _property_1; }
             set { _property_1 = value; }
        }

        [CategoryAttribute("Category One")]
        public int property_2
        {
             get { return _property_2; }
             set { _property_2 = value; }
        }
    }

    void ClearCatagory(string category_name)
    {
        CategoryAttribute target_attribute = new CategoryAttribute(category_name);

        Type my_class_type = my_class.GetType();
        PropertyInfo[] prop_info_array = my_class_type.GetProperties();

        foreach (PropertyInfo prop_info in prop_info_array)
        {
            AttributeCollection att_coll = TypeDescriptor.GetAttributes(prop_info);

            CategoryAttribute ca = (CategoryAttribute) att_col[typeof(CategoryAttribute)];

            if (ca.Equals(target_attribute))
            {
                prop_info.SetValue(my_class, 0, null);
            } 
        }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe I'm just not getting it (or you've summarized what's actually in your code), but it seems as though you're not implementing the use of properties correctly. Make sure you've [studied this thoroughly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w86s7x04.aspx) before attempting this level of complexity.

Comment: Your right in that this code is not actually using properties as you normally would. I'm attempting to use Refection and to scan through all the properties in a class and make changes to them based of the CategoryAttributes. However, my problem is that I don't know how to access the CategoryAttributes.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [MemberInfo.GetCustomAttributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwc6ew1d.aspx) instance method instead of `TypeDescriptor.GetAttriburtes`.

The call would be `object[] attributes = prop_info.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(CategoryAttriute), false)`.

Or you could use `TypeDescriptor.GetProperties` instead of `Type.GetProperties`  You shouldn't switch between using reflection and TypeDescriptor.

---

Also, the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwt979kt.aspx) for `Category.Equals` isn't exactly clear, but likely it implements reference equality (which is the default for C# unless a class specifically overrides it).  Which means that `Equals` will only return true if the instances being compared are exactly the same regardless of the value of `Category`.  If that is the case, then `ca.Equals(target_attribute)` will always be false because the references are different objects.

Try instead comparing the string value stored in the `Category` value.  Strings implement value equality so that `String.Equals` compares the values stored in the stings.

So replace

```
if (ca.Equals(target_attribute))
```

with

```
if (ca.Cateogry.Equals(category_name))
```

Comment: Thanks. That's good to know. My code actually is failing before the Equals(). I am trying to access the CategoryAttributes that I previously assigned to the the properties in my_class. My best guess was that that information could be extracted from the PropertyInfo objects returned by my_class_type.GetProperties(). However, its not there. So I am looking for another way to find it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much to shf301 for solving this. Here is a working version of the code:

```
    class my_class
    {
        [CategoryAttribute("Category One")]
        public int property_1
        {
                get { return _property_1; }
                set { _property_1 = value; }
        }
    }

    void ClearCatagory(string category_name)
    {
        Type my_class_type = my_class.GetType();
        PropertyInfo[] prop_info_array = my_class_type.GetProperties();

        foreach (PropertyInfo prop_info in prop_info_array)
        {
            CategoryAttribute[] attributes = (CategoryAttribute[]) prop_info.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(CategoryAttribute), false);
            foreach(CategoryAttribute ca in attributes)
            {
                if (ca.Category == category_name)
                {
                    prop_info.SetValue(my_class, 0, null);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class cls
{
        [Category("Default")]
        [DisplayName("Street")]
        public string Street { get; set; }
}

foreach (PropertyInfo propinf in cls.GetProperties())
{
  var category = prop.CustomAttributes.Where(x => x.AttributeType ==typeof(CategoryAttribute)).First();
sCategory = category.ConstructorArguments[0].Value.ToString();
}
```

This is how we could get value of CustomAttribute